# Go generics: invalid composite literal type T

Tags: go, generics, composite-literals

```
package main

import (
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
)

type NetMessage struct {
    Data []byte
}

type Route struct {
}

type AbstractParse interface {
    Parse(*NetMessage) proto.Message
}

type MessageParse[T proto.Message] struct {
}

func (p *MessageParse[T]) Parse(message *NetMessage) proto.Message {
    protoT := &T{}
    if len(message.Data) > 0 {
        err := proto.Unmarshal(message.Data, protoT)
        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }
    }

    return protoT
}
```

When I tried generic coding for Go, I encountered this problem:

> ./prog.go:23:13: invalid composite literal type T

What was the cause? Is there any way to fix it?

code link: https://go.dev/play/p/oRiH2AyaYb6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure you need Generics... but let's address your compilation error:

```
invalid composite literal type T
```

and the Go spec regarding [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

> The LiteralType's core type T must be a struct, array, slice, or map
> type (the grammar enforces this constraint except when the type is
> given as a TypeName).

The code at issues is:

```
type MessageParse[T proto.Message] struct {}

func (p *MessageParse[T]) Parse(message *NetMessage) proto.Message {

    protoT := &T{} // <- here
```

The generic type `T` is constrained on the type `proto.Message`. Looking at type [proto.Message](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/proto#Message) (which is an alias for type [protoreflect.ProtoMessage](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.28.0/reflect/protoreflect#ProtoMessage)) shows it is a Go `interface` type and *NOT* a core type. Thus it cannot be used to instantiate a composite literal.

You would get the [same compilation error](https://go.dev/play/p/iZQRt-u41Z9) in a non-Generics example like:

```
type mytype interface {
    SomeMethod() error
}

_ = &mytype{}  // // ERROR: invalid composite literal type mytype
```

Comment: the same error arises also when the type parameter doesn't have a core type at all, e.g. constraints with unions, etc.